# Display month wise report

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

I have this table

```
| box    | indate     |
 ----------------------
| 500    | 2015-01-19 |
 ----------------------
|200     | 2015-01-17 |
 ---------------------
| 1000   | 2015-03-19 |
 ---------------------
| 500    | 2015-03-7  |
 ---------------------
```

I want this Repot

```
| Year - Month| Total In box |
------------------------------
| 2015- 01    | 700          |
------------------------------
| 2015-03     | 1500         |       
------------------------------
```

Also I want to display in year wise report in php.

This is what i tried so far:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(indate,'%Y-%m'), SUM(box) 
FROM in GROUP BY YEAR(indate), MONTH(indate)
```

Comment: Is this an SQL query?

Comment: i tried                                                                                                 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(indate,'%Y-%m'), SUM(box) 
FROM in
GROUP BY YEAR(indate), MONTH(indate)

Comment: yes this is sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.
Just modify your query and use `SUM(box)` in place of `COUNT(box)`.
Like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(indate,'%Y-%m') as indate, SUM(box) 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY YEAR(indate), MONTH(indate);
```

And for Year wise report, just dont include the `MONTH` in Group By:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(indate,'%Y-%m') as indate, SUM(box) 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY YEAR(indate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format a date to show just the year and the month. And you can also group the result and combine that with a sum of the grouped rows.

Formatting a date-value in MySQL (i.e. Date, DateTime) you can use the [formatters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the date into specific format.

Check out this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7c0c/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(indate,'%Y-%m') as indateDate, sum(box) as totalBox FROM <your_table_name> GROUP BY indateDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 SELECT concat(YEAR(indate), '-', MONTH(indate)), sum(box)
 FROM
 reporttable
 GROUP BY YEAR(indate), MONTH(indate) ASC
```